# ReSharper warning for spurious ReSharper comments/attributes?

Tags: c#, resharper

In the course of time and after several refactorings, I often have code littered with spurious and unnecessary `ReSharper disable` comments and `[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "X")]` attributes. As code evolves, what used to be a valuable warning suppression is now not needed.

Is there a way to get ReSharper to warn me when these comments/attributes are no longer needed?

This would be especially useful for unit tests. For example, I'm often invoking the constructor of the class under test without assigning it to any variables, because it's useful to guarantee constructor behavior. So of course I'll put in the `// ReSharper disable once ObjectCreationAsStatement` comment. But then I'll often find a refactoring that assigns the constructed instance to a variable, and then the comment I put in to disable the warning is no longer needed and just clutters the code.

Comment: If there is a way, then I suppose the next question is: "and is there a way to disable that warning of spurious comments with a comment?" lol

Answer (score 1):

Per [the comment on this page](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-446848), you can enable [internal mode (instructions how here)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk//Extensions/InternalMode.html). Then...

> When enabled, there is code inspection "Redundant code inspection disable comment" under menu "ReSharper -> Options -> Code inspection -> Inspection severity".

Take note that...

> this inspection works well only after "ReAnalyze all files" in Solution Wide Analysis . When you type something in a source file, the inspection can generate false warnings. Also, it does not check attributes.